# QGIS-Feature "Generate band name with NetCDF EXTRA_DIM" - Which NetCDF attribute/variable does that refer to?

Tags: qgis, netcdf

According to the [changelog of QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog240/index.html#feature-generate-band-name-with-netcdf-extra-dim), the feature "Generate band name with NetCDF EXTRA_DIM" was implemented already in version 2.4.
The description says:

*The NetCDF provided extra dimensional information. This information provides metadata on each band. These metadata can be used to explain the name of each band. For example, the bands of a NetCDF file represents the temperature at a given depth. For the user, it is easier to select a band with depth information, rather than only the band number.*

This functionality is exactly what I was searching for. However, I couldn't find any information, how this *extra dimensional information* is saved in the NetCDF. Usually, I create multi-dimensional NetCDFs using the Python-API. What is the naming convention and/or attribute, needed for this *extra dimensional information*, so that QGIS can make use of it?